# Vue3 access array returned from imported .js composables

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vue-component, vue-router

```
setup() {
const { orders, orders_error, load_orders, profits } = getOrders()
load_orders()


console.log('ARRAY', profits)
let new_series = [{
  name: 'series1',
  data: profits.value
}]
return { new_series, orders, load_orders, orders_error, profits }
```

And this is the .js exported function:

```
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { projectFirestore, projectAuth } from '../firebase/config'
//import { ref } from '@vue/composition-api'

const getOrders  = () => {
    const user = projectAuth.currentUser.uid
    let orders = ref([])
    let profits = ref([])
    let profit = 0
    const orders_error = ref('')
    
    const load_orders = async () => {
        try {

            projectFirestore.collection('users')
                .doc(user)
                .collection('orders')
                .doc('845thfdkdnefnt4grirg')
                .collection('profits')
                .onSnapshot(async (snap) => {
                    // In this implementation we only expect one active or trialing subscription to exist.
                    let docs = snap.docs.map(doc => {
                            return { ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }
                    })
                    orders.value = docs
                    let last = 0

                    orders.value.forEach(element => {
                        console.log('ELEMENT', element.profit_cash)
                        profit = last + element.profit_cash
                        last = profit
                        profits.value.push(profit)
                        //orders.push(element.profit_cash)
                    })
                    //console.log('ARR', profits.value)
                    
                });
            
        }
        catch (err) {
            orders_error.value = err.message
            console.log(orders_error.value)
        }
    }
    load_errors()

    return { orders, orders_error, load_errors, profits }

}

export default getOrders
```

I'm able to print the profits array correctly between template tags but I can't inside the setup() function.
I just receive an object and I can't access to the array nested into it. Basically I need to set profits array inside new_series to plot cumulative profits in apexchart.

This is my DOM printing profits.value from the component:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5oM9.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your console.log('ARRAY', profits), you don't access profits.value, whereas you do do that everywhere else. The template understands how to access the value automatically when you return just profits from your setup function.

```
const profitsValue = profits.value;
console.log('ARRAY', profitsValue);
```

You can then use that value in your series and keep your current return statement from setup()